# How do I create a Glass effect in opengl?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics

I want to create an Effect in opengl that works a bit like windows aero but in a 3D environment to make frosted glass more realistic. But even after hours of searching I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Gimp is open source and has a glass filter. You could at least look at the code...

Comment: Google for "glsl glass shader"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend starting by blurring your glass (Here I'm assuming your glass texture is an RGBA texture, i.e, its partially translucent) by using a [Gaussian Filter](http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/11/gaussian-blur-filter-shader/). This would have to be done in a shader as you want whatever is behind the glass to be blurred as well. Then blend a white color with the resulting texture. To make it look better, have the white color be "strongest" at the edges of the texture and get progressively weaker towards the middle. [Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) would help with this.